# decoding base64 encoded zip file to get the original zip file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am uploading a .zip file in the front end and converting it to a base64 URL using the readAsDataURL() method. I am sending the URL string to my backend. I am not able to decode the string to get the original contents of the uploaded .zip file

```
import base64
from io import BytesIO

image_64_encode = "data:application/zip;base64,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"
starter = image_64_encode.find(',')
zip_data = image_64_encode[starter+1:]
file_data = bytes(zip_data, encoding="ascii")

d=base64.b64decode(file_data)

with open("zip_decode.zip", 'wb') as f:  

    f.write(d)
```

Please suggest me a way to extract the  original contents of the zip file from this URL

this is the function i am using to encode the zip file

```
andleFileUpload(e){
    let files = e.target.files;
    console.log("files are", files);
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    reader.onload=(e)=>{
        console.log("inside reader", e.target.result);
    const url="http://ec2-3-85-140-138.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5000/api/upload";
    const formData = {file: e.target.result}
    return post(url, formData)
    .then(response => console.log("result", response))
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure the encoded data is true? how do you encode it?

Comment: URL has a limitation on its length, try use HTTP POST instead.

Answer (score 0):

To write original contents of the uploaded .zip file into `zip_decode.zip`:

```py
with open("zip_decode.zip", 'wb') as f:  
    f.write(base64.b64decode(image_64_encode.split(',', 1)[1]))
```